# Varible dicotomica en R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy trasteando con R Studio y en uno de los ejercicios estoy bastante bloqueado.

En el ejercicio 3, me piden que cree una variable dicotomica que divida la era PreTrump y PostTrump a partir del 2017. Eso ya lo he realizado

```
    #### Ejercicio 3
    
    PreTrump <- estadosunidos %>%
          filter(`Edition` <2017) %>%
        
  
        
        PostTrump <- estadosunidos %>%
          filter(`Edition` >=2017) %>%
```

En el ejercicio número 4 me piden lo siguiente y estoy bastante bloqueado: Generar una tabla sumario indicando las medias de PR Rating y CL Rating agrupados en si son años PreTrump o PostTrump, estoy tratando de ordenarlo de la forma que muestro abajo aunque me da error, creo que viene porque no he creado una variable dicotomica como tal, pero realmente no sé como enfocarlo ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? Se lo agradecería.

```
      #### Ejercicio 4
          estadosunidos %>%
              summarize(
                mean(`PR rating`, `CL rating`)) #### Sacar la media
                order_by(PreTrump, PostTrump) #### Ordenar via Pretrump (antes del 2017) o PosTrump (Despues de 2017), definidos arriba
                      )
```

Answer (score -2):

En tu código del ejercicio 3, necesitas un `mutate` que crea una variable lógica que es "True" para la epoca pre-Trump y "False" en caso contrario, así:

```
trump_era <- estadosunidos %>%
               mutate(pre_trump = `Edition` < 2017)
```

Luego en el ejercicio 4 puedes agrupar usando esta variable:

```
estadosunidos %>%
  group_by(pre_trump) %>%
  summarize(media_PR = mean(`PR rating`),
            media_CL = mean(`CL rating`))
```